# Answer on Comment

Tags: support, questions, comments, accepted-answer

What should you do if you asked a question but the best answer that helped or the only answer is under the comments section?

1. Should you just answer your own question and quote the person under the comments?
2. Accept any answer?
3. If the comment was for clarification but helped your answer, what should you do in that case?

edit: apologies for the duplicate, I tried searching the site a couple of times... the related searches only appeared after I posted the question. I mustve been using the wrong tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're certainly welcome to post an answer that references the comment, if you would like to.

You shouldn't be accepting an answer that *doesn't* answer your question just because there is a comment that answers it.  That would be wrong and confusing for everyone involved.

If a comment isn't actually an answer, but lead you to an answer, then you can, if you want, write up an *actual* answer that incorporates that information and post it.  While we certainly appreciate this if you're able to take the time to write a quality answer, it's certainly not *required* of you if you don't want to or don't feel comfortable writing an answer.

Comment: @MattMcNabb There is no rep requirement to answer your own question.  A 1 rep user is allowed to do so.